# What is the status of rxandroidble and rxjava2?

Tags: rxandroidble

I just inherited a project which uses both rxandroidble and rxjava2 (and the associated rxandroid). The previous developer seems to have gotten away with using them together with the versions being just so... But updating any of the related dependencies cause various errors.

Am I correct in assuming rxandroidble is rxjava1 only at this point?

If so, when might there be a version for rxjava2?

Is there a safe (read: stable) way of having both coexist in the same app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxAndroidBle is RxJava2 compatible since version 1.5.0 released on 14th of March 2018

#### Original Answer:

> Am I correct in assuming rxandroidble is rxjava1 only at this point?

Yes, current stable release `1.4.3` is `RxJava1` only.

> If so, when might there be a version for rxjava2?

Soon™.

`RxJava2` version is worked on. Current status can be checked in [the official Github issue](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/72).

Status as of 26th Feb 2018: there is a [`1.5.0-SNAPSHOT` release](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/72#issuecomment-366424868) that is for `RxJava2`. (It is in a different namespace than `RxJava1` version)

> Is there a safe (read: stable) way of having both coexist in the same app?

Assuming you are talking about having `RxAndroidBle` and `RxJava2` and `RxAndroid` for the same version—yes it should be totally fine to have it in one app. There is also [an interop library](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Interop) for chaining both versions of `RxJava`.